# Using grid system

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

```css
.wrappers {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 10rem auto 10rem 10rem;
}

.header {
  background: #9575cd;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrappers">

  <header class="header">
    <h1>Earthly Branches </h1>

  </header>
</div>
```

[There is an image from chrome tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jEFv.png)

so the question is when i put these codes the web site looks like unresponsive design even if i used grid style. i am making something wrong but i don't know where.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good there is nothing you need to get it responsive just analyse it you're making a grid of 4 rows where the `height` three of them have `10rem` and other is `auto` and also you're making 12 equal columns and you have `header`
which is from the first to the last `column` so if you want the header to fit in `.wrappers` just make the `header` to fit all the columns like the following

```css
.wrappers {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 10rem auto 10rem 10rem;
  height: 40rem;
}

.header {
  background: #9575cd;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrappers">
  <header class="header">
    <h1>Earthly Branches </h1>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for answering but i have another divs and so i need to use 12fr. but also it still looks awful with your solution i used it.

Comment: I don't understand what the question exactly is, you want to center the header text?

Comment: i added an image. it shows us when we start to page 270px and above the contents are overflowing but the header and also its color are getting smaller than width.